# Remove last bar between links in nav

Tags: html, css

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/w4k70at5/

It's a realy simple problem but I'm a bit stumped.

I have a border between each link to separate them.

I don't want a border on the last link in the line.

I can remove the last border but can I remove the border after 'Link Six' and then when the page is resized remove the border on the last link on that line.

```
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav{
            margin: 50px;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
        }

        ul{
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
        }

        li{
            display: inline;
            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        }

        a{
            display: inline-block;
            border-right: 1px solid red;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            padding: 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li:last-of-type a{
            border-right: none;
        }
```

Comment: Not possible using CSS. You will have to resort to Javascript and do some weird calculations to find out where your `li`s wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform that using Jquery :

**1st possibility:**

Add a JQuery function which will add a class to your ul if it's the last one on the line:

```
$(function() {
    var lastElement = false;
    $("ul > li").each(function() {
        if (lastElement && lastElement.offset().top != $(this).offset().top) {
            lastElement.addClass("noborder");
        }
        lastElement = $(this);
    }).last().addClass("noborder");
});
```

And a CSS class to remove the border:

```
.noborder a {
    border: 0;   
}
```

If you want, you can remove your CSS rule with the previous solution:

```
li:last-of-type a {
    border-right: none;
}
```

JSFiddle 1: https://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/w4k70at5/4/

**2nd possibility:**

Same JQuery function but will not target the last `ul > li a` (because you already target it with your CSS):

```
$(function() {
    var lastElement = false;
    $("ul > li").each(function() {
        if (lastElement && lastElement.offset().top != $(this).offset().top) {
            lastElement.addClass("noborder");
        }
        lastElement = $(this);
    });
});
```

And a CSS class to remove the border:

```
.noborder a {
    border: 0;   
}
```

JsFiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/x93456gr/

Comment: Clever solution! I'd suggest you reset only the unwanted border, though.

Comment: @connexo Yup, updated my answer with both possibilities to perform that :)

Comment: @connexo Yes he can, the script will also target the last item in the list with `.last().addClass("noborder");`

Answer (score -3):

**FULL CSS SOLUTION**

https://jsfiddle.net/w4k70at5/

I added a class to the `<li>` that cause a problem, and this one is set up like following :

- When the screen size is under 590, I tell the class to show a right red border
- When screen size is above, border is transparent

I used [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) CSS function to perform this. This allows to set different class behiaviour for different variables (like the screen size in this case).

Comment: Now that *also* is the same totally dumb idea. What if the text of the items changes? What if they get translated into a different language and text lengths change? You ***don't*** hardcode your design for certain strings and string successions. Just **DO NOT. EVER.**